# Why this.props.dispatch gives error selectively error depending of the parent component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

Trying to build simple login and logout functionality in React-Redux.

I tried to add all logout procedures inside a function which is inside a button component.

I have a simple component called LogoutButton which should dispatch new actions and remove login-info from redux store which keeps the state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { update_user_id, update_user_email } from "../../actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export class LogoutButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
            this.props.dispatch(update_user_id(""));
            this.props.dispatch(update_user_email(""));
          }}
          >
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default connect()(LogoutButton);
```

This works when I insert LougoutButton into another class-based component (UserInfo.js) -component.

However when I add the same component inside NavBar (Function based component), I get a following error message.

```
TypeError: _this.props.dispatch is not a function
onClick
C:/koodi/off_front/src/components/views/LogoutButton.js:12
   9 | <button
  10 |   onClick={() => {
  11 |     localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
> 12 |     this.props.dispatch(update_user_id(""));
     | ^  13 |     this.props.dispatch(update_user_email(""));
  14 |   }}
  15 |   >
View compiled
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
```

I assume that the reason is how the components where LogoutButton is mounted are defined. Tried to google info but didn't find any.

I am very interested about the reasons what went wrong. Not only about the fixes in this particular case but also in more general.

Comment: Are you connecting to your store?

Comment: Logout-Button is connected via connect.
Class-based component which works is only connected via Provider
Functional based component ButtonAppBar has it's own mapStateToProps function:
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ButtonAppBar);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is because you're using 2 exports for the same component.

So pretty much only default export is connected to the store, and maybe you imported navbar using named export.

Comment: That was the reason!

By mistake I used named import in ButtonAppBar and wondered and wondered. Quite simple error in the end!